# Estou tentando colocara a hora atual em um projeto HTML e JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function carregar(){
var msg = window.Document.getElementById('msg')
var foto = window.Document.getElementById('foto')
var date = new Date()
var hora = data.getHours()
msg.innerHTMl = `Agora sao ${hora} horas`
}
```

e chamando no HTML

```
<body onload='carregar()'>
```

Comment: Ta mas onde está o problema ?

Comment: Na pagina era pra aparecer a hora e não aparece já testei a chamada do js com um alert e esta funcionando, os codigos perecem esta com a sintaxe correta mas não aparece a hora

Comment: Pode ser isso: `Document` esta com o `D` em maiúsculo deveria ser `document`, `msg.innerHTMl` o `L` esta em minusculo deveria ser `msg.innerHTML`

Comment: Troquei aqui mas nada mudou, To fazendo um curso pelo youtube meu codigo esta igual ao do professor mas nao ta indo... Teria outra maneira de colocar as horas alem dessa??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma série de problemas no seu código que faz com que a hora não seja inserida no seu elemento. Primeiro de tudo, para obter os elementos do documento, você deve utilizar `document` ao invés de `Document`.

Além disso, na linha em que você recebe a hora você utilizar uma variável chamada `data` ao invés da variável `date` que você criou para receber a instância de Date.

O terceiro problema no seu código, é que você utilizou `innerHTML` com o "l" minúsculo. Veja abaixo a correção do seu código:

```
function carregar(){
    var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
    var foto = document.getElementById('foto');

    var date = new Date();
    var hora = date.getHours();

    msg.innerHTML = `Agora sao ${hora} horas`;
}
```

OBS.: Não é obrigatório utilizar ponto e vírgula (`;`) no JavaScript, mas é recomendável para evitar alguns bugs que podem ocorrer. Além disso, é uma boa prática para deixar o código (na minha opnião) mais bonito e padronizado de certa forma.

Comment: Vlw irmão muito obrigado tava a uma hr nisso ja

Answer (score 0):

Anderson, tudo bem?

Aparentemente em seu código JavaScript há um pequeno erro:

```
var date = new Date();
var hora = data.getHours();
```

No script acima, você declarou uma variável que não foi declarada, que é o caso do data, o compilador está tentando reconhecer alguma variável mas não é possível, você necessita que esse data se transforme na variável que você declarou anteriormente.

```
var hora = date.getHours();
```

Neste caso, você conseguirá utilizar o método getHours pois a variável `date` é do tipo `Date`.

Para concluir, você montou uma string que será mostrada dentro de um elemento HTML que tem o id `#msg`, as linguagens de programação geralmente reconhecem uma string (frase) utilizando aspas duplas ou simples `string = "sua frase aqui";` ou `string = 'sua frase ${aqui} com alguma variável;`

Acredito que com estas dicas, você consiga dar seguimento à sua aprendizagem online.